# Add to Android layout programatically - then access what's been created from another method

Tags: android, layout

I'm creating a layout programatically and need to add a TextView. Only problem is, I need to make the TextView a global variable so it can be accessed within different methods (need to call the setText() method elsewhere).

```
ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(this);
LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(this);
linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
scroll.addView(linear);

TextView time = new TextView(this);
time.setText("Some text");
linear.addView(time);

new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    time.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
} // 'time' not accessible

public void onFinish() {
 time.setText("done!");
}
}.start(); */

this.setContentView(scroll);
```

So my problem is I'm creating the 'time' TextView but the CountDownTimer method can't access it. I try having the `TextView time = new TextView(this);` at the top of my code with the constructors so it's global, but this causes an exception - "unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo" and "null point exception". The exception doesn't indicate which line is causing the problem specifically, but it's the `TextView timeLeft = new TextView(this);` for sure!

Comment: Why aren't you using an XML layout file to define your view? Just curious.

Comment: Also, where in your code are you calling setContentView?

Comment: This is only part of the code (the part which I'm having a problem with it). The reason I'm creating the layout programatically as an indeterminate number of buttons are added to it earlier on. setContentView is (as above), at the bottom of the code after each button and the `time` TextView is added to the layout.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was focussing on the top of the code and didn't see setContentView(). Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make a member variable in your Activity (`mTime`).  Then CountDownTimer will be able to access the member variable at any time.

Alternatively, you can declare `time` final:

```
final TextView time = new TextView(this);
```

Comment: Have got it working now by declaring `time` as `final`, it is OK to do this? `time` is modified, every time the timer ticks down as it's a countdown timer. I'm a little confused as to what final variables do as it seems to be modifying it quite happily. Better get on Wikipedia and read up I suppose!

Answer (score 0):

You could assign an `id` (say: `myTextViewId`) to your `TextView` before adding it to a view, and later you can simply refer to that TextView by `findViewById(myTextViewId);`.

The same situation, if you inflate your TextView using an xml file, and assign an id inside of that. Then you can refer to that TextView by `findViewById(R.id.myTextView);`.

Or finally, since you can't make that TextView both `final` (it won't be initialized right away, nor in the constructor) and `class-level` (private, protected, etc..), i'd advice to make it a private variable inside your class.

To access it, your method should run in the ui thread, but a timer has its own thread, so you should use a `Handler`, and from your `TimreTask`'s run method just send an empty message to it. 
In your `Handler`'s `handleMessage(Message msg)` method you can access safely your `TextView`, either it being a member of your class, or just knowing its `id`.